# Sprockets/Rails: Find all files Sprockets knows how to compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, konacha

For Konacha, a Rails engine for testing Rails apps, we need a way to find all files that Sprockets can compile to JavaScript.

Right now we use something like

```
Dir['spec/javascripts/**/*_spec.*']
```

but this picks up `.bak`, `.orig`, and other backup files.

**Can Sprockets tell us somehow whether it knows how to compile a file**, so that backup files would be automatically excluded?

`content_type_of` doesn't help:

```
Rails.application.assets.content_type_of('test/javascripts/foo.js.bak')
=> "application/javascript"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can iterate through all the files in a `Sprockets::Environment`'s load path using the `each_file` method:

```
Rails.application.assets.each_file { |pathname| ... }
```

The block will be invoked with a `Pathname` instance for the fully expanded path of each file in the load path.

`each_file` returns an `Enumerator`, so you can skip the block and get an array with `to_a`, or call `include?` on it. For example, to check whether a file is in the load path:

```
assets = Rails.application.assets
pathname1 = Pathname.new("test/javascripts/foo.js").expand_path
pathname2 = Pathname.new("test/javascripts/foo.js.bak").expand_path
assets.each_file.include?(pathname1) # => true
assets.each_file.include?(pathname2) # => false
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam! So this will list `.../app/assets/javascripts/foo.js.bak` though, even though `/assets/foo.js` yields 404 (as it should). (And `Rails.application.assets.content_type_of '.../app/assets/javascripts/foo.js.bak'` yields `'application/javascript'`.) That's pretty strange. Is there some other filter I could apply?

Comment: I found a solution that seems to work well enough: `(pathname.extname == '.js' || Tilt[pathname])` -- this will pick up all files that either are already JavaScript (hence do not need to be compiled), or can be compiled by Tilt. This notably excludes `.js.bak` files.